# Stop Pandas TimeGrouper from forming incomplete groups

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Is there any way to stop `pandas.TimeGrouper()` from returning an incomplete group (ts1)? Currently I'm using the following to determine the number of incomplete group members and then using `.ix` to remove these rows (ts2). I was wondering if there's a better (or built-in) way of doing this? This was the only [`pandas.TimeGrouper` documentation](http://nullege.com/codes/search/pandas.tseries.resample.TimeGrouper?fulldoc=1) that I was able to find.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__

Out [1]: '0.15.0'

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2013', periods=365, freq='D')
random_numbers = arange(0, len(rng))
ts = pd.Series(random_numbers, index=rng)
num_days = 3
num_rows_to_drop = len(rng) % num_days
days = 'D'
timedelta_for_grouping = str(num_days) + days
ts1 = ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(timedelta_for_grouping)).transform('median')
ts2 = ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(timedelta_for_grouping)).transform('median').ix[:-num_rows_to_drop]
print ts1.tail(), ts2.tail()

Out [2]:
2013-12-27    361.0
2013-12-28    361.0
2013-12-29    361.0
2013-12-30    363.5
2013-12-31    363.5
Freq: D, dtype: float64 
2013-12-25    358
2013-12-26    358
2013-12-27    361
2013-12-28    361
2013-12-29    361
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to filter the len of the groups (according to the minimum of the resample period)

```
In [47]: g = pd.TimeGrouper(timedelta_for_grouping)

In [48]: ts.groupby(g).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3).groupby(g).transform('median')
Out[48]: 
2013-01-01     1
2013-01-02     1
2013-01-03     1
2013-01-04     4
2013-01-05     4
2013-01-06     4
2013-01-07     7
2013-01-08     7
2013-01-09     7
2013-01-10    10
2013-01-11    10
2013-01-12    10
2013-01-13    13
2013-01-14    13
2013-01-15    13
...
2013-12-15    349
2013-12-16    349
2013-12-17    349
2013-12-18    352
2013-12-19    352
2013-12-20    352
2013-12-21    355
2013-12-22    355
2013-12-23    355
2013-12-24    358
2013-12-25    358
2013-12-26    358
2013-12-27    361
2013-12-28    361
2013-12-29    361
Freq: D, Length: 363
```

Comment: Thanks this produced the desired result. I'm trying understand the your solution, could you explain why you used `.groupby(g)` the second time after `.filter()`? I've tried without it and I get an `AttributeError`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ``.filter()`` returns a DataFrame (and not a grouper), so you need to regroup it (this grouping is pretty cheap to do though).

Comment: upvoted! what if I want to remove incomplete groups only at the start and not at the end